# Multiple inheritance ambiguous method definitions

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Consider Python multiple inheritance:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'a'
    def y(self):
        return "A"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        self.name = 'b'
    def y(self):
        return "B"

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'c'
    def y(self):
        return "C"

class D(C, B):
    def __init__(self):
        C.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
```

When creating an instance of `D` it can be seen that as Python goes through each constructor it reassigns `self.name` and therefore the value of `self.name` is, as expected, the **last** value assigned to it:

```
>>> foo = D()
>>> print(foo.name)
b
```

However, for the method `y()` it seems that the method assigned is the **first** method assigned to it:

```
>>> print(foo.y())
C
```

**Why the discrepancy between which attributes are assigned?** What are the rules? The Python manual in fact has a section on [multiple inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance), however I don't see this topic mentioned there.

Note that this question is not homework, but it is adapted from a lesson in the wonderful [Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python](https://www.edx.org/course/mitx/mitx-6-00-1x-introduction-computer-1841) course.

Comment: Why would you expect any different? `C.y` doesn't call any of the parent class methods, unlike `C.__init__`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `B.y()` is defined after `C.y()`, so I would expect that the definition of `B.y()` would have replaced the definition of `C.y()`. This would be much in the same sense as B()'s `self.name` replaces the value of C's `self.name`.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. `D` inherits `y` from `C`, as that's the first parent to define it. The attribute is different as you're explicitly calling through the various different `__init__`s. If e.g. `C.y` called `B.y`, things would be different.

Comment: You **explicitly** call parent methods in `D.__init__`, while you do no such thing in `y`. There is no other difference here.

Comment: If you want to understand how Python multiple inheritance works, you'll need to read about the Method Resolution Order: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/. Check out what `D.__mro__` is set to to understand what `y` is picked.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you, it appears that the answer to the question will be in that page. I read only up to the phallus just now, but I'll be sure to go over it again (and probably again). You can go ahead and post that link (or a quote from the appropriate part of it) as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is really a duplicate then; closed as such.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I did review the question linked, but I discounted is as I am not using super() and I did not know enough at the time to generalize the content there. In the interest of helping people searching for information in the future, I would recommend either editing that question to be more general (i.e. not mention `super()` explicitly) or to reopen this question as the general case.